# Alternative to USB and DVD ROM Boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I'm trying to install Kali Linux to my old (and empty HDD) Q6600. However I'm facing issues with booting it via USB, all I see is black screen with cursor. (The bootable USB was created with UNetbootin). Additionally, the DVD drive is dead, too.

So, is there any other way I can install the distro to my PC?

**Specs**:

Q6600 with Intel DG43NB

4GB DDR2 RAM

500G HDD

Comment: any luck with the pendrivelinux tool?

Comment: Does that come for Mac?

Comment: I'm trying pendrivelinux with CrossOver to check how it works.

Comment: there's also 'linux live usb creator' and i've heard of YUMI

Comment: +1 for Universal USB Installer from pendrive, but it only works on Windows machines. Unetbootin often give these problems... if you can't find anything that works on Mac, I'm sure it's not that hard to find a Windows guy in your neighbourhood. It only takes a few minutes to create.

Comment: Can you just use PXE?

Comment: I'll try PXE now as CrossOver didn't work for me. :(

Comment: If you have access to Gparted, use it to ensure the partition created by Unetbootin has the "active"flag set. I've had older computers that just freeze (much like in your case) attempting to boot a drive without that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the iso directly with dd:

`sudo dd if=<iso image> of=<block device> bs=1M`.

For example, if the Kali Linux iso was `kali.iso` and your USB stick was `/dev/sdc`, then the command would be `sudo dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`

Comment: I believe link-only answers should be avoided due to zealous webmasters moving content around and breaking those links.

Comment: Sorry, just doing my best to teach someone to fish. I've updated the answer to have more substance.

Comment: I don't believe the sites in the Stack Exchange network operate under that principal. They want to provide answer to questions with little/no signal to noise. See the discussion of links at [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Say the image was from an 8GB USB stick, and the destination usb stick is 16GB, is there any issue?  I've heard that when doing dd from one hdd to another, they should have the same gemetry.

Comment: First of all, the image wasn't created with dd, it's a hybrid iso, meaning that it's a regular iso image that has a partition on it so it can be written to a USB stick. Beside that though, there should be no issue writing an image created from a smaller drive to a larger one. You'll just have a lot of wasted space, which isn't relevant to writing a Kali ISO image to a USB stick.

Comment: I used almost equivalent method to install Kali Linux, so I'm marking this answer as accepted. :)